# Haskell left arrow operator alternative

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm new to haskell and functional programming in general and I have a problem with monads. Let's say I have got a list of filenames:

```
-- do block --
let filenames = ["file1","file2"]
```

and I want to generate a list of those files' content, using list comprehensions:

```
let content = [str <- readFile f | f <- filenames]
```

Ofc, this kind of usage is not valid.
As I understand this kind of "assignment" can be used in do block, when "chaining" the result with the next instruction.

Is there maybe an alternative way to use the left arrow (or >>=) operator. I imagine sth like this:

```
let content = [leftArrAlter $ readFile f | f <- filenames]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start with the simpler list

```
let content = [readFile f | f <- filenames]
```

`content` has type `[IO String]`; it's a list of `IO` actions, each of which can produce a `String` when executed.

What you would like is something of type `IO [String]`: a single `IO` action that, when executed, gives you a list of `String` values.

That's where the `sequence` function comes in. In this case, we only need to consider the specialized version that has type `[IO String] -> IO [String]`:

```
content <- sequence [readFile f | f <- filenames]
```

We can also use `traverse`, in particular the specialized version with type `(FilePath -> IO String) -> [FilePath] -> IO [String]`:

```
content <- traverse readFile fileNames
```

---

For reference, the general types of the two functions:

```
sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

We used `[]` as our `Traversable`, and `IO` as our `Monad`/`Applicative`.

Comment: I'd also mention `mapM`, which is (now) equivalent to `traverse`, and its flipped version `forM`, which often makes for more readable code (`forM fileNames $ \f -> do {multiple IO statements involving f}`).